# How to restrict developers to use reflection to access private methods and constructors in Java?

Tags: java, security, reflection

How to restrict developers to use reflection to access private methods and constructors in Java?

Using normal Java code we can't access private constructors or private methods outside of a class. But by using reflection we can access any private methods and constructors in a Java class.

So how can we give security to our Java code?

Comment: This would be a nice option to have for signed jars. "Under no circumstances, allow reflection against classes in this jar file". But I think, there is no such feature.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run your application using a [`SecurityManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) and a sufficiently restrictive [security policy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html).

There's a [short summary in the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) and extensive information in [the security documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Add `checkPermission()` method in all of your private method/constructor.
checkPermission using `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(int n)` by assert `callerClass=selfClass`.

The `getCallerClass` returns the class of the method `realFramesToSkip` frames up the stack (zero-based), ignoring frames associated with `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()` and its implementation. The first frame is that associated with this method, so `getCallerClass(0)` returns the Class object for `sun.reflect.Reflection`.

```
public class PrivateConstructorClass {

    private PrivateConstructorClass() {
        checkPerMission();
              //you own code go below
    }

    void checkPerMission() {
        Class self = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(1);
        Class caller = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(3);
        if (self != caller) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalAccessError();
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to test reflect, it will fail:

```
public class TestPrivateMain {

    Object newInstance() throws Exception {

        final Class<?> c = Class.forName("package.TestPrivate");

        final Constructor<?> constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        return constructor.newInstance();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object t = new TestPrivateMain().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...But it was a good try indeed in my opinion..Unstable API 's should not be there in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You (as the developer of the code in question) cannot do that.

The end user, who runs the application, could install a SecurityManager that forbids reflection.

Comment: Of course he can. He installs the security manager during startign up of his application.

Comment: That is not an option unless he is the developer of the application. I was thinking more about the case where he "wants to restrict developers [presumably of the application] to use reflection" against the methods he'd like to keep private.

Comment: What prevents him to have a static initializer in his classes that installs a security manager? And ofc throiws an exception that prevents class laoding, if he can't install it?