# How is Groovy able to access private methods of a Java class?

Tags: java, groovy, jvm, bytecode, access-modifiers

Groovy can access private methods and variables of a Java class. How does Groovy do this behind the scene? Is it because of the use of `invokedynamic` bytecode instruction which is used by `MethodHandle` class? I think Java uses `invokespecial` instruction for calling `private` methods and `invokevirtual` for `public` right which respects access modifiers?

Comment: It uses reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy is written in Java, so it hopefully doesn't rely on the byte code directly, it doesn't it using the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

For more details check for [`java.lang.reflect`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=java.lang.reflect) in the source code, you will then see how it uses the Reflection API behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Java anyway by using reflection, for example, this method will set the value of a private static field...

```
public static void setStaticField(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, value);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not set field '" + fieldName + "' of type '" + clazz.getName() + "' to: " + value, ex);
    }
}
```

Notice `field.setAccessible(true)`

This can be prevented by having an appropriate Security Manager Policy set up. See [How to restrict developers to use reflection to access private methods and constructors in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566626/how-to-restrict-developers-to-use-reflection-to-access-private-methods-and-const)

Comment: Yes, in Java I can use reflection, but how does groovy do? Is groovy also use reflection?

Answer (score 1):

you can use java.lang.reflect

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method

// ....

Method method = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod('initializeSeoCode')
method.setAccessible(true)
java.lang.Object r = method.invoke(a)
```