# Groovy script and Java class without getter and setter with private fields, how does it access the fields?

Tags: java, groovy

I have java class like

```
class Test {

   private String field1;
}
```

no other methods or getter and setter.

in a groovy script I have:

```
def test = new Test()

test.field1 = "foobar"
```

and this works even if the field is private and no getter/setter are defined. How does it works?

The project is a java project and the groovy script is executed via `GroovyShell` so the `Test` class is compiled by java (no methods added by groovy).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Groovy accesses the field directly (internally by using reflection). That's actually one of the pitfalls of Groovy that made me switch away from it: it's way too easy to accidentally access an objects internals even when you didn't mean to.

Comment: I wonder how this holds up when you use a JVM with the module system enabled. Those tend to not like reflective access to privates.

Comment: @Jorn Interesting point, it would be nice to know how it works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy uses [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to access fields, so there is not real "privacy" here. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929264/how-is-groovy-able-to-access-private-methods-of-a-java-class), people discuss it more in details. Also check this [article](https://touk.pl/blog/2012/07/12/private-fields-and-methods-are-not-private-in-groovy/).